# Copy content to new content by using button

Tags: sapui5

I'm using SAPUI5 XML view

`myView.view.xml`

```
<f:SimpleForm id="form1"/>
   <f:content id="content1">
     <core:Title text="" />
     <m:Label text="Label A" />
     <m:Input value="10/5/2548" enabled="false" />
     <m:Label text="ชั้นที่/ปีที่" />
     <m:Input value="1" />
     <core:Title text="" />
     <m:Label text="Label B" />
     <m:Input value="3.25" />
     <core:Title text="" />
   </f:content>
</f:SimpleForm>
```

`myController.controller.js`

```
addNewContent:function(){
   var content = this.getView().byId("form1").getContent();
   this.getView().byId("form1").addContent(content);
}
```

Error message

> not valid for aggregation "content" of Element
>   sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm#__xmlview1--form1

I want to copy content `(id="content1")` to button when click `addNewContent` Button

Anyone help thanks

Add more information
[this is what i want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER4H3.png)

Comment: 1) Content is already  in the form - do you want do duplicate the content of the form in the same form?
2) <f:content id="content1"> is an aggregation of SimpleForm so you cannot use an "id" here

Answer (score 0):

## Technically

The [`getContent()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm/methods/getContent) method returns an array `sap.ui.core.Element[]`.

The [`addContent()`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm/methods/addContent) method takes a single `sap.ui.core.Element` as parameter.

So you need to do something like this:

```
this.getView().byId("form1").addContent(content[0]);
```

or this:

```
oForm = this.getView().byId("form1");
content.forEach(oControl => oForm.addContent(oControl))
```

or if not using ES6:

```
oForm = this.getView().byId("form1");
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    oForm.addContent(content[i]);
}
```

## Functionally

It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Based on your code snippet, you are trying to copy from and paste to the same place...

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry for not clear question.
I want to copy(duplicate) form1 to button after click Add button.

Comment: I've try your solution, but It's seems like it cut content[i] to bottom not copy. Please help thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the "copy...to button" part. Let's walk through it: before clicking on the button, you have a form with some fields, and a button; what would you like to see after clicking the button?

Comment: It’s should be bottom.., after click the button I want to copy form for example is user input family member then after click add they will see another input form block (same as they input 1st family member) to input another family member.

Comment: I think I now understand what you are trying to achieve. I suggest this approach: Underneath the form, add a list control and bind its items aggregation to an empty array in some model. When the user clicks the button, read the entered form details and add it to the array in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you, try to clone form and append it to the container.

XML view

```
<Button text="+" press="cloneContent" /><!-- Button for cloning -->
<f:SimpleForm id="form1" editable="false" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" title="Address" labelSpanXL="3" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" labelSpanS="12" adjustLabelSpan="false" emptySpanXL="4" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" emptySpanS="0" columnsXL="1" columnsL="1" columnsM="1" singleContainerFullSize="false">
  <f:content>
    <core:Title text="" />
    <Label text="Label A" />
    <Input value="10/5/2548" enabled="false" />
    <Label text="ชั้นที่/ปีที่" />
    <Input value="1" />
    <core:Title text="" />
    <Label text="Label B" />
    <Input value="3.25" />
    <core:Title text="" />
  </f:content>
</f:SimpleForm>
<VBox id="contentHolder"></VBox><!-- clone form holder -->
```

Controller

```
cloneContent: function(oEvent){
    var oForm = this.getView().byId("form1");
    if (oForm) {
        oFormClone = oForm.clone();
        oFormClone.setTitle("");
        var oHolder = this.getView().byId("contentHolder");
        if (oHolder) {              
            //oHolder.removeAllItems();//if you want to remove all the previous added item you can uncomment this line
            oHolder.addItem(oFormClone);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Take care of binding after clone. You can use `oHolder` to rebind if you have any issue.

Comment: ReferenceError: oFormClone is not defined.
oForm.clone() is not the function :(

Comment: Which SAPUI5 version you are using? Kindly update your complete code.

Comment: here is my index.html.
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
         src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
         data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize_plus" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m, sap.tnt"
         data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
         data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"sap.ui.demo.toolpageapp": "./"}'
         data-sap-ui-preload="async">

So this is the latest version right?

Comment: Instead of `oFormClone = oForm.clone()`, use `var oFormClone = oForm.clone()`

Comment: I have created a [example using plnkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/FqrwK2FekGihLa99?preview) where it is working fine.